# How to get the server path to the web directory in Symfony2 from inside the controller?

Tags: php, symfony

The question is as follows:

How can I get the server path to the web directory in Symfony2 from inside the controller (or from anywhere else for that reason)

What I've already found (also, by searching here):

This is advised in the cookbook article on Doctrine file handling

```
$path = __DIR__ . '/../../../../web';
```

Found by searching around, only usable from inside the controller (or service with kernel injected):

```
$path = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../web';
```

So, is there absolutely no way to get at least that 'web' part of the path? What if I, for example, decided to rename it or move or something?

Everything was easy in the first symfony, when I could get like everything I needed from anywhere in the code by calling the static sfConfig::get() method..

Comment: I had the the same problem and had to use the getRootDir(). It is REALLY irritating that you cannot get the full path to the /web folder! :P

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There's actually no direct way to get path to webdir in Symfony2 as the framework is completely independent of the webdir.

You can use `getRootDir()` on instance of kernel class, just as you write. If you consider renaming `/web` dir in future, you should make it configurable. For example AsseticBundle has such an option in its DI configuration (see [here](https://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php#L63) and [here](https://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/assetic.xml#L40)).

Comment: Thank you. I was going to use the getRootDir method if nothing else popped up, it seems to be the most reasonable and universal method to do this.

Answer (score 44):

To access the root directory from outside the controller you can simply inject `%kernel.root_dir%` as an argument in your services configuration.

```
service_name:
    class: Namespace\Bundle\etc
    arguments: ['%kernel.root_dir%']
```

Then you can get the web root in the class constructor:

```
public function __construct($rootDir)
{
    $this->webRoot = realpath($rootDir . '/../web');
}
```

Answer (score 18):

You also can get it from any ContainerAware (f.i. Controller) class from the request service:

- If you are using apache as a webserver (I suppose for other
  webservers the solution would be similar) and are using
  virtualhosting (your urls look like this - `localhost/app.php` then you can use:

  ```
  $container->get('request')->server->get('DOCUMENT_ROOT');
  // in controller:
  $this->getRequest()->server->get('DOCUMENT_ROOT');
  ```
- Else (your urls look like this - `localhost/path/to/Symfony/web/app.php`:

  ```
  $container->get('request')->getBasePath();
  // in controller:
  $this->getRequest()->getBasePath();
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the catch is - I'm not the only developer on the project and I know for sure that some of them don't use virtual hosts and some do, me included. So the solution should be more universal than that... That's why (and taking into account the second answer) I'll probably use the getRootDir() method as more universal one.

Comment: If you want to get the directory with no request context this one will not work isn't it? Like commands?

Answer (score 15):

You are on Symfony, think "Dependency Injection" ^^

In all my SF project, I do in parameters.yml:

```
web_dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../web"
```

So I can safely use this parameter within controller:

```
$this->getParameter('web_dir');
```

Answer (score 12):

My solution is to add this code to the app.php

```
define('WEB_DIRECTORY', __DIR__);
```

The problem is that in command line code that uses the constant will break. You can also add the constant to app/console file and the other environment front controllers

Another solution may be add an static method at AppKernel that returns **DIR**.'/../web/'
So you can access everywhere

Answer (score 12):

UPDATE: Since 2.8 this no longer works because assetic is no longer included by default. Although if you're using assetic this will work.

You can use the variable `%assetic.write_to%.`

`$this->getParameter('assetic.write_to');`

Since your assets depend on this variable to be dumped to your web directory, it's safe to assume and use to locate your web folder.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/assetic.html

Answer (score 2):

For Symfony3 
In your controller try

```
$request->server->get('DOCUMENT_ROOT').$request->getBasePath()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$host = $request->server->get('HTTP_HOST');
$base = (!empty($request->server->get('BASE'))) ? $request->server->get('BASE') : '';
$getBaseUrl = $host.$base;
```

Comment: Isn't this for getting request url, not for filesystem path, as asked?

Answer (score 0):

Since Symfony 3.3,

You can use `%kernel.project_dir%/web/` instead of `%kernel.root_dir%/../web/`