# How to get web directory path from inside Entity?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I researched the [How to Handle File Uploads with Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) and I don't want to hard-code the `__DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();` path because maybe in future I will change the `web/` directory. How to do it more flexible? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265788/how-to-get-the-server-path-to-the-web-directory-in-symfony2) but it doesn't answer the question how to do it more flexible from inside the Entity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't use entity class as a form model here. It's simply not suitable for that job. If the entity has the `path` property, the only valid values it can stores are: `null` (in case lack of the file) and string representing the path to the file.

1. Create a separate class, that's gonna be a model for your form:

   ```
   class MyFormModel {
        /** @Assert\File */
        private $file;

        /** @Assert\Valid */
        private $entity;

        // constructor, getters, setters, other methods
   }
   ```
2. In your form handler (separate object configured through DIC; recommended) or the controller:

   ```
   ...
   if ($form->isValid()) {
       /** @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile */
       $file   = $form->getData()->getFile();

       /** @var \Your\Entity\Class */
       $entity = $form->getData()->getEntity();

       // move the file
       // $path = '/path/to/the/moved/file';

       $entity->setPath($path);

       $someEntityManager->persist($entity);

       return ...;
   }
   ...
   ```

Inside form handler/controller you can access any dependencies/properties from DIC (including path to the upload directory).

---

The tutorial you've linked works, but it's an example of bad design. The entities **should not** be aware of file upload.

Comment: I understood. Thanks. But how to use a lifecycle callbacks to manage a deletion of the file with your code?

Comment: Based on previous experience I suggest you store absolute path (or at least relative to webroot path) as well..

Comment: Create a listener, that subscribes `preRemove` (or `preDelete`) event (see [how to](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html)) and unlink the file there.

Answer (score 1):

To access the root directory from outside the controller you can simply inject '%kernel.root_dir%' as an argument in your services configuration.

```
service_name:
    class: Namespace\Bundle\etc
    arguments: ['%kernel.root_dir%']
```

Then you can get the web root in the class constructor:

```
public function __construct($rootDir)
{
    $this->webRoot = realpath($rootDir . '/../web');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a variable in your parameters.yml. 
Like this you'll can change path when you want.

for example :

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
# Upload directories
upload_avatar_dir:        /uploads/avatars
upload_content_dir:       /uploads/content
upload_product_offer_dir: /uploads/product-offer
...
```

Comment: How to obtain it inside an Entity?

Comment: It's not the responsibility of your entity to know where the document is store. Yo can move this responsibility to your controller. Or you can add a path attribute to your entity

Answer (score -1):

I handled this by creating an abstract class that Entities may extend if they are handling file uploads as described in the Symfony Documentation.  I created the files array so I could create a copy of the existing file path in the set methods so it could be deleted off the file system on a successful update or delete without defining any additional properties in the Entity proper.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;

abstract class FileUploadEntity
{
    private $files;

    public function __set($name, File $value)
    {
        $this->files[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        if (!is_array($this->files)) $this->files = array();

        if (!array_key_exists($name, $this->files)) {
            return null;
        }
        return $this->files[$name];
    }

    public function getUploadRootDirectory()
    {
        return $this->getWebDirectory() . $this->getUploadDirectory();
    }

    public function getWebDirectory()
    {
        return __DIR__ . "/../../../../web/";
    }

    public function getUploadDirectory()
    {
        $year = date("Y");
        $month= date("m");

        return "images/uploads/$year/$month/";
    }

    public function getEncodedFilename($name)
    {
        return sha1($name . uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
    }

    // this should be a PrePersist method
    abstract public function processImages();

    // This should be defined as a Doctrine PreUpdate Method
    abstract public function checkImages();

    // this should be a PostPersist method
    abstract public function upload();

    // this should be a PostUpdate method and delete old files
    abstract public function checkUpload();

    // This should be a PostRemove method and delete files
    abstract public function deleteFile();
}
```

Comment: Hm, I see that you used the `__DIR__ . "/../../../../web/"` too, but my question is how to avoid it.

Comment: I'm not sure there is one.  It seemed like the best i could do was define it in one place.