# How can I access bundle web directory from Symfony Command?

Tags: symfony

I am creating a Symfony Bundle where I have my commands, entities and all the logic that I need.

But in one of my commands I need to store files in `/web/bundles/mybundle/images`.

I've been googling a lot and I can't find anyway to get my bundle web root directory from a command.

Is there any Symfony function to get my bundle web root directory?

Comment: A related question, with some approaches that might be useful, although there doesn't seem to be a particularly tidy way to do so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265788/how-to-get-the-server-path-to-the-web-directory-in-symfony2

Comment: Thanks, I've already seen that question, but I think is some kind of "ugly" approach :)

Comment: Check the source code for the assets:install command.  That sounds like what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the Symfony2 core which will give you directly the path of your web directory...

One possible solution:

`$path = realpath($this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/../web');`