# Get Symfony public (/web) folder in command

Tags: php, symfony

How to get the Symfony public folder on commands.

On request to get the `/var/www/myapp/web` folder I can call:

```
$this->get('request')->getBasePath();
```

but how to get the public folder on a command and I don't want something hardcoded like `%kernel.dir%/../web`, because it should also work when the installation use public not web as folder or other custom folders.

Comment: You could define your "web" folder as a variable in parameters.yml and read it from there if you want to have dynamic web folder...

But %kernel.dir%/../web seems to be the best choice.

Comment: This answer looks also nice to find the /web folder: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27949505/4074148 (not tested)

Comment: but for this assetic bundle is needed dont want to make requirements only for finding the public folder.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that. The /web folder is referenced only in the Virtual Host web server (apache/nginx) directive. Symfony does not need to know that the /web folder is the one where the visitor lands. The app.php and app_dev.php do everything relatively.

Moreover, it "kinda" does not make much sense to have such requirement. If you're developing a command, you could add an optional Option to it. Something like "--webDir=web", where "web" is the default value. If the web server is configured otherwise, the command user will pass a different value like "--webDir=myWebDir", e.g.

Comment: ok make sense that its not important for symfony to know the public folder, I looked at the `assetic bundle` and there it also needed to be configured where the public folder is thx for answering